# Haskell MultiWayIf extension: When is it considered useful syntactic sugar?

Tags: haskell, formatting

The new [`MultiWayIf`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.2/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#multi-way-if) extension (available with GHC 7.6) allows guard syntax in an `if`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiWayIf #-}
fn :: Int -> String
fn x y = if | x == 1    -> "a"
            | y <  2    -> "b"
            | otherwise -> "c"
```

But I don't find it better than the old way:

```
fn :: Int -> String
fn x y | x == 1    = "a"
       | y <  2    = "b"
       | otherwise = "c"
```

Has it sense in other cases?

Comment: I am not sure if this question is suited for Code Review, maybe it should get migrated to SO.

Comment: Flow, I put in codereview because is probably more subjective that a question in SO. It, IMHO, is a "Best practices and design pattern usage" question

Comment: Good point, seems reasonable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unsurprisingly, it's mainly useful when the `if` is *not* the top-level expression. Say:

```
forM_ [1..100] $ \i ->
  putStrLn $ if | i `mod` 15 == 0  -> "FizzBuzz"
                | i `mod` 3 == 0   -> "Fizz"
                | i `mod` 5 == 0   -> "Buzz"
                | otherwise        -> show i
```

I happen across similar cases quite often - up to this point this required either deep `if` trees or mis-using `case` in some way.